# Endless Redirect Loop by htaccess rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/apm/.* [NC]
RewriteRule apm/(.*) https://someothersite.net/~mc/apm/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)mydomain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain2.net/_APM/dist [R=301,L]
```

what I want to do is :
1. 
if user goes to mydomain2.net/apm/ redirect to https://someothersite.net/~mc/apm/ ..

1. some1 goest from mydomain1.com to mydomain2.net (any page) , then redirect to   http://mydomain2.net/_APM/dist .

first one working correctly but second one giving endless loop . Any Ideas please.

and the htaccess file is on mydomain2.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP referer doesn't change after a 301 redirect. You need to exclude the `_APM/dist` request from the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)mydomain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !_APM/dist http://mydomain2.net/_APM/dist [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got access to the site config file? (Under linux: "/etc/apache2/sites-available/site")

You should use [Apache VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html). It's meant for that.

You would get something like

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention , both my domains are not on same hosting .

Comment: That redirect based on referral causing problem .